# How to use mongodb lookup with group and calculate total

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections

1.Product collection==>

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 154,
    "name" : "Chocolate Heaven",
    "price" : 7
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 155,
    "name" : "Tasty Lemons",
    "price" : 8
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 156,
    "name" : "Vanilla Dreams",
    "price" : 9
}
```

2.Order collection==>

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "product_id" : 154,
    "quantity" : 10
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "product_id" : 155,
    "quantity" : 3
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "product_id" : 156,
    "quantity" : 6
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "product_id" : 154,
    "quantity" : 1
}
```

I am expecting an out put for a product what is the total price using mongodb

156         Vanilla Dreams          9           6           54

```
db.getCollection('order').aggregate([
        {$group : {_id :{ product_id : "$product_id"}, sellCount : { $sum : "$quantity"}}},
        {$lookup : { from : 'product',localField : '_id.product_id' , foreignField :'_id',as: 'prodDetails' }},
        {$match: {prodDetails: {$ne: []}}}
]);
```

1. could you help me figure out the correct query.
2. How to create view for this out put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try running a pipeline that just uses two steps **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** and **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** as follows:

```
db.product.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "order",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "product_id",
            "as": "orders"
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "total": {
                "$multiply": [
                    "$price",
                    { "$sum": "$orders.quantity" }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```